# macOS Sierra How do disable Siri prompt?

Tags: macos, siri, remote-control

After upgrading my wife's iMac to macOS Sierra 10.12.0, she chose to disable Siri from the System Preferences for her own reasons. Now, every time we press the play/pause button on one of the [older white infrared Apple remotes](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/28/Apple_Remote.jpg), the following dialog appears:

[image: "Do you want to enable Siri?" dialog window in macOS Sierra.]

Is there a way to prevent this from displaying, even if it means somehow nuking Siri altogether?