# How to get macOS Sierra to stop asking me to enable Siri

Tags: macos, siri

macOS Sierra is constantly displaying an "Enable Siri?" dialog. If I pick cancel it just pops up again 5 seconds later.

[image]

How do I tell macOS Sierra to stop asking?

Comment: Have you tried enabling it, then going into **System Preferences** and turning it off?

Comment: that seems to have done it .. crossing my fingers

Comment: Please ask a new question for the earpod problem as the answer may likely be different and it is kind of confusing of having both topics mingled into one.

Comment: Or check https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/252259/prevent-earpod-play-pause-button-from-activating-siri-on-macos-sierra first which seems to cover that already.

Comment: This is almost a duplicate https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/258816/how-to-completely-disable-siri-on-sierra

Comment: did you try this on work laptop? i seem to get this issue on my work laptop and unable to enable Siri. Might be some company policy.

Answer (score 49):

If you've been mistakenly triggering the Siri pop-up when your finger mistakenly hits the top right area on the Control Strip, you can remove the Siri icon.

Go to:  → System Preferences → Keyboard, then click the "Customize Control Strip" button on the bottom, or on newer OS X, "Touch Bar Settings" then "Customize Control Strip"

Move your cursor to the Control Strip (which will now be in Edit Mode), and click and Drag the Siri Icon back onto your screen into the area with all the unused Control Strip widgets.

Comment: This is correct.  Nice one.

Comment: Thanks, this did not only solve my problem, but also brought to my attention that there's useful stuff I can add to the touch bar.

Comment: would not let me drag items off the little taskbar in that dialog, instead the entire bar worth of default items was moving around..  but I could drag them around on the taskbar itself when in that mode, so dragged the siri icon to the far left to get it away from the fingerprint reader
.... that is the least user friendly config screen I've seen in a while.

Comment: Awesome. That's a really useful feature. Wish Apple had put half as much effort into making that discoverable as they put into making Siri available in Mac OS. I replaced her with a button to pull up the launch pad.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden that's what I had to do... to be more specific, I dragged it into the trash can.

Comment: This was useful... I did not know you can customise the touchbar. I've added the volume control which only gives you access to volume and then the close button for it if you press it by mistake which it happens extremely often.

Comment: Slightly different steps for Ventura: System Settings -> Keyboard -> Touch Bar Settings -> Customize Control Strip

Answer (score 4):

Accept by clicking **Enable Siri**, then go into **** → **System Preferences** → **Siri** to *uncheck* **Enable Siri**. That should take care of it.

Comment: This does NOT end it.

Pressing the Mic button accidentally, will trigger the whole cycle over again.

Comment: THIS DOES NOT WORK

Comment: This worked nicely and addressed 2 different things that were triggering the prompt.