# Repeatedly prompted to activate siri and iTunes opens -- possibly Kinesis related

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, siri

About once per minute, my computer asks me whether I want to activate Siri as in [this other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/257317/how-to-get-macos-sierra-to-stop-asking-me-to-enable-siri). Per that question, I have enabled Siri then dis-enable it from system preferences -- did not fix my problem

At the same time, iTunes opens.

It just started about ten minutes ago when I plugged in my Kinesis Advantage Pro keyboard. Are these related and how can I stop Siri popping up continually after toggling the preference?

Comment: In my case, I have deleted iTunes, and it magically reinstalls it each time the prompt pops ... Thinking about downgrading this shit