# How to completely disable Siri on Sierra?

Tags: macos, siri

I have answered 'No' to Siri initial prompt, but I can still see it in my process list. I've tried to kill it, but it loads again immediately. How can I unload and remove Siri from my Mac?

[image]

Comment: Under **System Preferences** > **Siri**, have you unchecked the **[] Enable Siri** checkbox? As to removing Siri, in the voice of HAL 9000 from 2001: A Space Oddesy, I'm sorry Anton, I cannot allow you to do that. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, I found out the whole procedure by myself, thanks to @blueberryfields and @bret7600.

First of all you need to disable System Integrity Check to be able to edit the com.apple.Siri.plist file.

1. Reboot in Recovery mode by restarting your Mac and holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. It can take more time to boot as usual, that's OK, just be patient.
2. In the top menu go to **Utilities** and open Terminal.
3. Type `csrutil disable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type `reboot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reboot again.

Now you should edit the com.apple.Siri.plist file.

1. Open Terminal.app
2. Type `sudo plutil -replace Disabled -bool true /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Siri.plist`

Now you should re-enable System Integrity Check. It is there for a reason.

1. Reboot in Recovery mode by restarting your Mac and holding <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.
2. In the top menu go to **Utilities > Terminal**.
3. Type `csrutil enable` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Type `reboot` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to reboot again.

Now if you check Activity Monitor - you should see no traces of Siri there.
You can repeat this procedure with `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.assistantd.plist` to fully disable it.

Comment: Mhm, okaaay, I will definitely not going to install Sierra...

Comment: i didn't need to restart in recovery mode, just restart at the end of the instructions.

Comment: This almost worked. `/System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Siri.plist: file does not exist` However `com.apple.Siri.agent.plist` does exist. Will marking that as 'Disabled' have the same effect?

Answer (score 8):

Der Flounder post [Blocking Siri on macOS Sierra](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/blocking-siri-on-macos-sierra/) contains plist files that keeps her from running and suppresses her from the menu bar:

#### com.apple.assistant.support.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Assistant Enabled</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### com.apple.Siri.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StatusMenuVisible</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UserHasDeclinedEnable</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

There are also [mobileconfig files](https://github.com/rtrouton/profiles/tree/master/DisableSiri) to have it automatically disabled by the scripts [linked there](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2016/09/20/blocking-siri-on-macos-sierra/) too.

---

Notes:

- you might have to fiddle your way around the SIP (System Integrity Protection mode) before you can actually modify these files.
- the referenced files are copied over from the equivalent settings for iOS, and may not necessarily work as expected on Sierra. Use with care!

Comment: those instructions are incomplete at best - the plist files appear to be dated mobile versions, and there are other problems with the process, including sierra prevents editing of the files in /System/Library/LaunchDaemon directory

Answer (score 1):

Using `defaults` command to operate settings in `.plist` file is much easier and quicker.

```sh
# Disable "Ask Siri"
defaults write com.apple.assistant.support "Assistant Enabled" -bool false

# Remove siri icon from status menu
defaults write com.apple.Siri StatusMenuVisible -bool false
```

The daemon `assistantd` is still running. I don't recommend disable it cause you need to disable SIP.

Comment: This you can do from the System Preferences.app GUI, so it really does not answer the question of how to COMPLETELY disable Siri.