# Canceled Mac OS Big Sur update still takes 8 GB of space

Tags: software-update, big-sur, storage

I recently downloaded the installer for Mac OS Big Sur, to update my MBP from Catalina. After the download finished, and before I clicked "Install", I had about 35 GB of space left on my machine.

However, a little after clicking continue, I clicked cancel (the round "X" button). And now the installer will not accept clicking install again, saying it required 8 more GB's. I checked my storage again, and it shows about 26 GB left. So over 8 GB taken like this!

I assume these are temp install files for Big Sur, and if so, how can I remove them and resume installation of Big Sur?

Comment: It is in either some temporary location or in /Applications (https://superuser.com/questions/1604610/after-a-failed-big-sur-update-of-17gb-that-was-previously-available-only-5gb-re). Either way, as suggested in the question that @anki linked to, you can use a program to find the location of large files or folders. I have used GrandPerspective myself and it works well.

Comment: Updates (in mojave) used to be in /Library/Updates https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/375597/unable-to-delete-pkg-files-in-library-updates/375663#375663 and were protected by SIP. I don't know how things changed in Catalina+. If you find the files but can't delete them, ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks to the Daisy Disk software and the linked question, I managed to find these files. In Finder, open Macintosh HD (or the name of your hard drive), and search for "UpdateBundle". Removing the latter folder, about 12 GB of space was freed and I managed to resume the install normally. Thanks everyone!